# fire server click event after executing a jquery ajax call from client click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

Have an asp imagebutton with client side and server side events.
client side method calls a webmethod via jQuery Ajax.
in OnSuccess event, need to fire the server side event.

**Code snippet :**

```
<asp:imagebutton id="imgbtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/icon.gif" OnClick="return CheckAPP();"></asp:imagebutton>

function CheckAPP() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "testPage.aspx/ValidateSerialNumber",
        data: "{strSerialNumber:'" + strSerialNumbers + "',strManufPartNo:'" + strMPartNo + "',strCountryCode:'" + '<%=strCountryCode %>' + "',strIpAddress:'" + '<%=strIpAddress.Trim %>' + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            return true;
        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}


Private Sub imgbtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles imgbtn.Click
  SaveInfo()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery trigger():

**EDIT:** Call the CheckApp() function from OnClientClick:

```
<asp:imagebutton id="imgbtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/icon.gif" OnClientClick="return CheckAPP();"></asp:imagebutton>
```

And return `true` or `false` to trigger `click` event:

```
function CheckAPP() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "testPage.aspx/ValidateSerialNumber",
        data: "{strSerialNumber:'" + strSerialNumbers + "',strManufPartNo:'" + strMPartNo + "',strCountryCode:'" + '<%=strCountryCode %>' + "',strIpAddress:'" + '<%=strIpAddress.Trim %>' + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            return true;
        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this would only trigger the client side event